# How to set a x-header in OTRS6 Postmaster filter with regexp?

Tags: regex, filter, otrs

I am trying to set the x-header for a dynamic field to the first number found in the e-mail subject with a regexp ^[^\d]*(\d+).
I can't figure out the right syntax for the set email header value field:
[image]

Comment: Try `^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example. It extracts the first number found in the Subject and adds it to the dynamic field. How this is done is also explained in the hint on the left site

[image]

If the Subject of the Mail is "test 124 14 test 44", then the dynamic field has the Value "124"